# show Dictionary Keys When Press Dot

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dictionary

I have a table with two columns "Keys" And "Values".
and this dictionary holds `<key, value>`.

```
var dic = Context
    .Table
    .Select(mc => new { mc.str_SystemName, mc.str_Value })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary(k => k.str_SystemName, v => v.str_Value);
```

In ASP.NET 4 is possible to show dictionary keys with intellisense (I mean like when you press dot and it shows properties).

example: dic.key1
             key2
             key3

Comment: Are your keys known at compile time?

Comment: Only what's known at compile time can be made to show up like this

Comment: Also, if it's not known at compile time, `dic.key1` won't resolve regardless - unless you're doing some `dynamic` trickery.  Are you looking for `dic[key1]`?  Note that this doesn't know what is a key (which is only known at runtime), only what could be a key (i.e. the types must match).

Comment: I don't know exactly, may be they known after compile is done?
My point is possibility to use intellisense function to show up a column's values. if there is another solution for this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can.  Intellisense will show all of the Methods, Properties, events, etc.  Unless I am mistaken, key values are stored in the Dictionary at runtime.

If you know the columns before you compile and want to use intellisense to get Key names, you could make an enumeration and use that as your key value.

ie. `Dictionary myDict<ColumnEnum, Object>;`

Then make an enumeration with the Column names.

```
Enum ColumnEnum ={id, name, address, etc};
```

Intellisense would show all the column names when you type "ColumnEnum."